# Ruby OpenSSL Cipher

Tags: ruby, openssl, encryption

When I instantiate a cipher with AES GCM like so, it works:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
```

However, I get an unsupported cipher error when I do the following (the way mentioned in the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+%28AEAD%29)):

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :GCM)
```

Is there any difference between the two (i.e. is the former equivalent to the latter)?

```
>> OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
=> "OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013"
```

Comment: What version of ruby? Looks like some of that is new in ruby 2.0

Comment: @FrederickCheung Ruby 2.0.0p247